# How do I look for the most starred git repositories under an organization

Tags: git, github

How do I look for the most starred git repositories (ordered descending) under an organization in github

https://github.com/apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use github's advanced searching function, enter the user name (`apache` as an example), then sort it in "Most stars":

[image]

> https://github.com/search?l=&o=desc&q=user%3Aapache&ref=advsearch&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=✓